# $(\frac1{n^{\sqrt n}})^{\frac1n}=(n^{-\frac{\sqrt n}{n}})^{}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a little bit confused by this one. Is this correct?

$$\left(\frac1{n^{\sqrt n}}\right)^{\frac1n}=\left(n^{-\frac{\sqrt n}{n}}\right)^{}=\sqrt{n^{-\frac1n}}$$

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

**Edit: Is it okay that I changed the question a little bit ?**

Comment: Maybe this is a little bit stupid question, shall I delete it ?

Comment: There are no stupide questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your original question: Yes, the statement equality holds:

$$\left(\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}\right)^{\Large\frac{1}{n}} = \left(n^{-\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\Large\frac{1}{n}}= \left(n^{-\Large\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}}\right)$$

For your  edited/added (second) (in)equality: Please note that, in fact
$$\left(n^{-\Large\frac{\sqrt n}{n}}\right)^{}\neq \sqrt{n^{-\Large\frac1n}}$$
What we *do have* is this: $\quad\displaystyle \left(n^{-\Large\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}}\right) = \left(\large n^{\large-\sqrt{\Large\frac 1n}}\right)$

Comment: Yes, definitely did clear things up, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Yeah this is correct because 
$$\left(\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}\right)^\frac{1}{n} = (n^{-\sqrt{n}})^\frac{1}{n}= (n^{-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}})$$

Answer (score 2):

Recall:
$$\left(\frac{1}{b^n}\right) = b^{-n} \tag{1}$$
$$\left(a^n\right)^m = a^{nm}\tag{2}$$

Now we have:
$$\left(\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}\right)^\frac{1}{n} = \left(n^{-\sqrt{n}}\right)^\frac{1}{n} \tag{applying equation (1)}$$

$$\left(n^{-\sqrt{n}}\right)^\frac{1}{n} = n^{-\sqrt{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}} \tag{applying equation (2)}$$

Simplifying:
$$n^{-\sqrt{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}} = n^\frac{-\sqrt{n}}{n}$$

**Therefore, yes, the statement in your question is correct.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Seems to be exactly right.